# ¿Como calcular el total de cada fila?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito mostrar el total (`.total`) de cada fila (`.numero`).

Obviamente mi problema es el `loop` que lo estoy realizando mal.

Ahora mismo tengo el siguiente código:

```
<table id="tabla" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Numero</td>
      <td>total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="numero">1</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="numero">2</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>

  $(document).ready(function() 
  {    
    $(document).on('focusout','#factor',function()
    {
      $("#tabla").each(function()
      {
        var factor = $("#factor").val();
        var numero = $("#tabla tbody tr").siblings().text();         
                  var r = parseInt(factor) + parseInt(numero);
                  $(".total").text(r);
                  console.log(r); 
      })    
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las modificaciones que necesitas hacer son las siguientes:

- [**Opcional**] Para dar una mejor experiencia al usuario, te recomiendo utiliza el evento `input` en lugar de `fousout`.
- Debes usar `parseInt` para obtener el valor como un entero (*o `parseFloat` para obtener el valor como un decimal*)
- Los elementos que debes buscar e iterar, son las filas de la tabla (`eg: $("#tabla tbody tr").each`)
- Por cada fila (`eg: $tr = $(this)`) debes buscar las celdas con las clases `.numero` y `.total` (`eg: $tr.find('.numero')`)

### Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#factor').on('input', function() {
    var factor = parseInt($("#factor").val(), 10) || 0;
    
    $("#tabla tbody tr").each(function() {
      var $tr = $(this);
      var numero = parseInt($tr.find('.numero').text(), 10);
      var r = factor + numero;
      
      $tr.find('.total').text(r);
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabla" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Numero</td>
      <td>total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="numero">1</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="numero">2</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Sumar: <input id="factor" type="number" value="0"/>
```

Comment: excelente, gracias por la edicion y respuesta @marcos

Comment: tengo una duda de como funciona tu codigo, quisiera que me dijeras que funcion cumple el 10) || 0 . No lo tengo claro ahora mismo

Comment: El método [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) necesita que se establezca la base sobre la cual se calcula el numero, en este caso, es `10`. Si llegara a suceder que `parseInt(valor, 10)` devolviera `NaN` el calculo fallaria, por lo que adicione `|| 0`, esto quiere decir que si `parseInt` devuelve `NaN` entonces el valor sera igual a cero.

Comment: ahora si, gracias